# JavaFX 8: How to avoid clipped off the text in TableView's column header?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

When I double click the divider in the header to resize the column width, the column header is not enough to display the column name if the length of text in the cell all is shorter than the column name. This name will be clipped.

[image]

I want to resize the column to the width of text in column header if all the text in its cells is shorter than this header name.

Are there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Just curious, did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen with jdk8u20 at least not on Linux. Maybe this bug was fixed in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum width of the column;

```
columnname.setMinWidth();
```

This way the column can still scale larger but stops at the width you set.